# How to use eclipse project from github for Android development

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, android-studio

I need to modify Android 4.2 ZBarCodescan java application in Windows 7 x84 computer.

Its source code is located in https://github.com/xuxingliu922/DeviceSDK

I installed Android Studon and selected Github import command. It shows error message that git.exe does not exist.

I have also Visual Studio Community Edition installed and it contains git.exe :

```
 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git

03.02.2016  22:28            20˙160 git.exe
```

It seems that this github code supports eclipse only.

How to change this app? Should git.exe copied or installed or should eclipse used instead ?
Or should this code copied into local drive and imported as eclipse project ?

I changed git.exe in settings path as recommended in comment. Now both test and  checkout command cause strange error

[image: gitexeerror]

Also as shown in image, next menu selectoion "Import project..." becomes active.
I selected Check out project this should be active.

How to modify this project?
I need to modify source code in my compüuter only, no need to submit changes back to github. I dont have write access in this repository

Comment: Open Android Studio preferences, type `git` on the search box and check if the `Path to git executable` is correctly set (you can use the test button on the right)

Comment: I changed path to git.exe. Now both test and github commands produce strange error. I updated question

Comment: Are you using the git client from https://git-scm.com/downloads or did you point your path to git to an existing git on your machine?

Comment: I changed path to existing `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git.exe` Maybe microsoft git.exe is not compatible

Comment: Maybe that is the problem. Could you try using the git implementation from https://git-scm.com? Reading this Q&A https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week04jan15/10-questions-about-visual-studio-support-for-git/ it seems that may be some minor differences between git implementations (maybe git --version is not implemented in Microsoft's git and it's giving you this error)

Comment: Thank you. I was now able to clone it but encountered strange error on apk build. I updated question. How to fix this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106787/discussion-between-antonio-and-andrus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

To allow Android Studio to use git, open Android Studio preferences, type `git` on the search box and check if the "Path to git executable" is correctly set (you can use the test button on the right)

For your second problem, it seems that may be some minor differences between git implementations (maybe git --version is not implemented in Microsoft's git and it's giving you this error). Use the git implementation from http://git-scm.com

Comment: There is realted question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103262/solve-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files-define-exception