# How to fix android Multiple dex files define exception

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dex

Android 4.2 ZBarCodescan java application needs to compiled in Windows 7 x64 computer.

Its source code is [located here](https://github.com/xuxingliu922/DeviceSDK).

Android Studio is installed, and code is imported using Github import command. 
In gradle file API was changed to 23

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

according to

[How to use eclipse project from github for Android development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099379/how-to-use-eclipse-project-from-github-for-android-development)

Android studio Build APK command produces exception

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Trying to fix this by adding  lines

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

to both project gradle lines according to

[Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility)

causes  errors

```
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoJellyBeanMr2;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoStubImpl;
```

How to fix this ?

[Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility) recommends to examine dependency tree. How to get this tree in  Android Studio and how to fix it ?

After removing android-support-v4.jar  exception

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Still occurs.

Update. I tried to importfixes branch using  https://github.com/cricket007/DeviceSDK/tree/fixes
url but Test button and import produce error

[image: error]

How to import this branch ?

Comment: On the command line type `gradle dependencies` to get the dependency tree. Could you post it?

Comment: Why don't you add your Gradle file so we can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Is that Github link your repo? Why is android-support-v4 in the libs folder and not being built by Gradle?

Comment: You still have not followed my earlier comment to show the build.gradle file

Comment: Also, overall, this feels like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). You just want a Barcode Scanner? Use [this library](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner). I'm having a hard time follow the non-english commit messages and that repository you linked to is riddled with problems.

Comment: @cricket_007 My device is special scanner. It has 2 green and 2 white LEDs in addition to camera. Library you referenced seems to support only camera. One should position camera to correct square in android screen. This is not reasonable for 8 hrs scanning.  Repo in question controls device scanner via serial port. Using it scans quickly by using green led indicators, no need to look into android screen.

Comment: And the build.gradle for the `SmartDeviceSDK` module?

Comment: And there are no copied JAR files between the `SmartDeciveSDK/libs` and `TestDEMO/libs` directories? The only other thing that would cause a conflict is if the **contents** of the JAR files overlap. You have have to manually open them to see that though.

Comment: You could also follow the instructions it gives you to [get more output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project)

Comment: @cricket_007 File names in both project are different. I added `--stacktrace --debug --info` command line options. Same error as previously appears. I updated question.

Comment: @antonio I tried in terminal window `C:\DeviceSDK>gradle dependencies` but but error `'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio? I have forked the Github repo and made it work with Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [pull request](https://github.com/xuxingliu922/DeviceSDK/pull/3) to the library after getting it to work in Android Studio.

If you get this error when trying to build

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Or you don't see that, but any error saying `local.properties` is missing when doing an import, then add a `local.properties` file that points to your Android SDK location, then trying to import/rebuild.

For example on a Mac, that file would contain this line, but obviously change the file path to point at your respective SDK's location

```
sdk.dir=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
```

Once done with that, it should load into Android Studio without a problem.

The code was also tested on a 4.2 emulator.

---

The easy way via a Git Terminal (could do the same with Git Desktop).

```
git clone https://github.com/cricket007/DeviceSDK /path/to/download/
cd /path/to/download/
git branch fixes
```

Then import /path/to/download/DeviceSDK into Android Studio as Import Project Gradle

---

The long way (via Android Studio)

> Use **https://github.com/cricket007/DeviceSDK.git** as the Git repo

[image: Import]

> Open Project, you can ignore most errors that popup
>
> Go the the Menu Bar, select **VCS > Enable Version Control Integration**

[image: Enable VCS]

> Choose Git
>
> Go back to **VCS > Git > Branches**
>
> Checkout fixes as a new local branch

[image: Pick Branches]

[image: Checkout]

> Name the branch.
>
> Choose **Force Checkout** if prompted
>
> I don't know what clicking the Run button does with a Gradle project, but you should open Gradle View on the right side and open TestDemo, select **installDebug**

[image: Gradle View]

From here on you need the solution above for the `local.properties` file and enable ADB debugging on a physical device or test on an emulator.

Comment: Where to get working project ? Should your repository imported into Android Studio again to get it ? In Android Studio in Windows, prompt appears on load and SDK location is fixed automatically.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do `git checkout <url>` to get the repo, and then `git checkout fixes`  to switch to the implemented branch.

Comment: How to import fixes branch to Android Studio? I tried to import url `https://github.com/cricket007/DeviceSDK/tree/fixes` but got error repository test failed. I updated question with error image.

Comment: So you want to checkout and modify code from Github repo, but don't understand Git? You need to use the command line or the git GUI to switch branches using `git checkout `... See more here https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell#Switching-Branches

Comment: Or just download a zip of the branch and extract it https://github.com/cricket007/DeviceSDK/archive/fixes.zip

Comment: I asked about doing this from Android Studio GUI. git clone command should used to retrieve project. git checkout send data to github. How to run your project in Android emulator or in debug mode in device? After pressing Run button and selecting Android emulator only empty Nextus image appears. I connected scanner with USB cable and debugging is enabled in its settings but Android Studion complains that there is no device in USB .

Comment: No, `checkout` is used to "checkout" branches & files. `push` is the only command that sends to a remote repository.

Comment: Or you can use the initial Github project. And forget about the branch. My pull request was merged.

Answer (score 5):

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;

It happens becuase you are adding twice the same class.

In your case you are using:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

The `appcompat-v7` has a dependency with the `support-v4`.
You have the `android-support-v4.jar` in your libs folders.

Remove the android-support-v4.jar (you don't need it because appcompat has already it).

Comment: I dont understand how exactly to fix: should I remove the line ` compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'` from file or delete some file ? I havent used java and gradle before, I have used only Visual Studio

Comment: @Andrus You can remove the android-support-v4.jar because the appcompat dependency just has it

Comment: I removed android-support-v4.jar from all places. `Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;` exception still appears. how to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same error I had to comment out the following line in my build.gradle file:

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

Comment: Why comment that line? Just remove all the other lines that you manually added that compile from the libs folder

Comment: I commented out this line in both projects. Now Build APK returns error `C:\DeviceSDK\SmartDeviceSDK\src\com\smartdevicesdk\barcodescanner\zxing\FormatSelectorDialogFragment.java:9: error: package com.google.zxing does not exist
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;` how to fix?